# Determine block belong to which file path in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have multiples input paths for my job. Ex:

```
    //Driver.class
        for (String s : listFile) {
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(s), SequenceFileInputFormat.class);// ex: /home/path1, /home/path2, ...
        }
        .....
    //Mapper.class
        public void map(Text key, Data bytes, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                .....
            }
```

My question is that is there any way to determine the current pair (key, value) in map() function belong to which file?

Comment: You may extract file path from `JobConf` in `configure(JobConf)` method. See example in javadocs: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `SequenceFileInputFormat` as your `InputFormat`, the `SequenceFileInputFormat` uses `SequenceFileRecordReader` as its `RecordReader` and extends `FileInputFormat` whose method `getSplits()` return the `FileSplit` which owns the `Path`, and  of course the `SequenceFileRecordReader` can get the `Path`. So what you need to do is that when you get `key` and `value` make one of them contains the `Path`, which need to do in the `RecordReader`.

Here are the steps:

- Make a custom valClass who contains the `original value` and the `path`:

  ```
  class YourValClass implements Writable {
      Writable value; // your orginal value
      Path path; // the path you want
  }
  ```
- Make a custom `InputFormat` class extend the `SequenceFileInputFormat`, and override the `createRecordReader()` method to return to your custom `RecordReader` :

  ```
  class YourInputputFormat extends SequenceFileInputFormat<YourKeyClass, YourValClass> {

      @Override
      public RecordReader<YourKeyClass, YourValClass> createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException {
          return new YourRecordReader(); // return your custom RecordReader
      }
  }
  ```
- Make the custom `RecordReader`, in which you can combine your `value` and `path` together:

  ```
  class YourRecordReader extends SequenceFileRecordReader<YourKeyClass, YourValClass> {
      Path path;

      @Override
      public void initialize(InputSplit inputSplit, TaskAttemptContext taskAttemptContext) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          super.initialize(inputSplit, taskAttemptContext);
          FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) inputSplit;
          this.path = fileSplit.getPath(); // assign the path
      }

      @Override
      public YourValClass getCurrentValue() {
          YourValClass val = super.getCurrentValue();
          if (null != val) {
              val.path = path; // set the path
          }
          return val;
      }
  }
  ```

Now you can get the `path` from `YourValClass` value.